# How to store string into remote file?

Tags: shell, command-line, remote-access

How to store string into remote file ?
I need to override content of file on remote machine (I have username, password and ip and can access through ssh) with some string from command line.
How to achieve this on linux ?

Comment: `ssh user@host -c "echo $yourstring>>/path/to/file"`

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the file in one operation with `ssh`:

```
ssh user@host "echo \"$local_variable\" > /path/to/file"
```

However, this is risky - What if there's a double quote character in the local variable? In Bash, you can get around it by quoting the value:

```
ssh user@host "echo $(printf %q "$local_variable") > /path/to/file"
```

The much **simpler and safer** way to do this, and avoid any weird escaping problems, is to simply save the contents to a file locally and then copy it over with `scp` or `rsync`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to ssh you can execute any command on the remote machine:

```
ssh username@remotehost.com /usr/bin/mycommand
```

(For example you could echo a string into a file if you like)

if you want to get rid of the password prompt, you could use SSH Key Authentication:

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
scp .ssh/id_rsa.pub username@remotehost.com:~/.ssh/authorized_keys2
```

Once your key is on the remote machine, you can use ssh without password. (Warning: Using a key which is not password protected, could be risky)